# Not getting 2 images to display PHP

Tags: php, image, where-clause

What am I missing the first image displays but not the second one

```
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT link FROM images WHERE ID = 1");   
$stmt->bind_param("i", $ID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($link);
$stmt->fetch();

?>
<img id="result_img" src="<?php echo $link; ?>" />
```

// the above images displays but not the one below

// $link displays a picture its a links stored in a cell from the column link in the table

```
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT link FROM images WHERE ID = 2");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $ID);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($link);
$stmt->fetch();
?>
<img id="result_img" src="<?php echo $link; ?>" />
```

Comment: What's the value of `$link`in the last instruction?

Comment: The image is not displaying because the link the `src` value is incorrect.